# How I check if a variable is a "class" reference

Tags: java

How do I check if a given variable is a `Class` (generic type)? I really don't know how to ask the question better, but let's consider this code:

```
Object[] o = new Object[] { "string", 12, MyClass.class, new MyClass() };

for (int i = 0; i < o.length; i++) {
    if (o[i] instanceof String) ...       // TRUE for [0]
    else if (o[i] instanceof Integer) ... // TRUE for [1]
    else if (o[i] instanceof ???) ...     // TRUE for [2] ???
    else if (o[i] instanceof MyClass) ... // TRUE for [3]
    else ...
}
```

How do I check the type of the third element of the `o` array?

Comment: Have you tried (o[i] instanceof Class)?

Comment: Hmm probably with `o[i].getClass().equals(MyClass.class)` ?

Comment: @A4L I need to know if it's *any* class.

Comment: I would mind why would you have such array to begin with, unless is just pure curiosity.

Comment: **Thank you all**, I just missed that in fact `.class` was just a *Class instance*. I will accept an answer in minutes.

Comment: @lorenzo-s then go with `instanceof Class`!

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I have an array of many object in an Android project, each one have an item in a list, and when clicking an item I have to perform different task depending on type (i.e. *Strings* open URLs, *Classes* open Activities of that class, etc...)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `instanceof` to test if it's a class (of any type):

```
if (o[i] instanceof Class)
```

Use `==` to test if it's a specific class:

```
if (o[i] == MyClass.class)
```

Class literals are effectively static constants, so there's only one of each class literal per JVM.

---

Note: If there are multiple class loaders in play then the test for `==` may be false even though it "should" be true if the two instances were loaded using different class loaders. In this case, even `o[i].equals(MyClass.class)` will be false.

Answer (score 3):

Use like bellow with `instanceOf` operator

```
o[i] instanceof Class
```

Answer (score 1):

```
else if (o[i] instanceof Class) ...
```

Exactly the same way you'd check if it was an `Integer` or `String`. If you want to use the generic type parameter, it'll have to be the `?` wildcard:

```
else if (o[i] instanceof Class<?>) ...
```

Since generic information is erased at runtime, and it doesn't seem you want to test that it's a specific class anyway.

Answer (score 1):

MyClass.class is a literal of type Class, so instance of Class should do.